# Should login information be cached?

Tags: asp.net

Currently when a user logs in, I store the user id in a cookie.
This is to prevent the need from checking that the user is logged in when accessing certain pages.

However, when I test with two browsers whereby the user account is deleted in one browser, the cache is still present in the other browser and thus the user is still considered logged in.

This problem can be solved by not using the cookie approach - check the db every time.  But this is a waste of cpu (or is it?)

Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how restrictively you will do in security policy. If you want to make every requests safety, you should check the DB every time and even though to generate new tokens for every request one by one. And you shouldn't considering the resources usage then.

But if you just want check the logged-in status, you should use `Session` for your requests, instead of `Cookie`: (Store the userID in session, and check it by request at the code behind)

The differences of `Session` and `Cookie` are:

1. `Cookie` is stored in client side (which is unsafe to you), and `Session` is stored in server side (which is under your control and can be trusted).
2. `Cookie` will be existed until you clean it or set its expired time, and `Session` will be deleted if you closed the browser or no-action for period time.
3. etc...

Comment: Session will not be deleted immediately when you close the browser, but its cookie will (so you cannot go back to it)